# PhoneGap Plugin ExternalScreen loading external assets

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the "ExternalScreen" plugin for phonegap, and I am loading a 'local' html file. This 'local' file won't load any of my 'external' assets. In other words, the HTML file links to JavaScript libraries and CSS Stylesheets, but it is not loading them. Even if I do inline styles, it won't load images.

Any idea why no assets are being loaded outside of the .html page with PhoneGap ExternalScreen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the "localHTMLResource" function of the plugin, and it has been fixed.

Thanks @andytrice